# Python or R function to group multivariate chemical data based on % similarity of all variables tested

Tags: python, r

I'm a novice when it comes to programming but use GIS software to spatially plot samples (n=2000) that have multiple variables (n=16 elements) tested. I'm trying to use Python or R (or any language really) to statistically break out chemically related groups based on the relative similarity (%) of all the tested elements.

Example using + or - 10% of the value:

```
          Al    Na    K     Si
Sample1   1     2     3     4
Sample2   1.5   2.5   3.5   4.5 
Sample3   1.05  2.1   3.1   1
Sample4   0.95  1.9   3.1   3.8
```

Desired result:

- Sample1 would be in a group with Sample 4 (all four values are within 10% of each other).
- Sample2 would be on its own.
- Sample3 would also be on its own as even though the three first elements are within 10% of Sample1, the last element (Si) is not and thusly isn't grouped.

I've looked at a few threads but none seem to relate all variables together and will only group based on one.

Comment: Do you want to do this based on proscribed thresholds--you define your threshold to be "within 10%" and all variables must meet that threshold? Or are you looking for a statistical clustering method that will take your data as input and give you back clusters where the statistical method determines the rules (such as a k-means clustering algorithm)?

Comment: If the former - how do you want to handle transitiveness? Let's say Sample A is just over 10% lower than Sample B, and Sample C is just under 10% higher than Sample B. Your rules would put A and B in the same group, and put B and C in the same group, but **not** put A and C in the same group. So is it grouping your looking for, or pairwise relationships? (And of course you can imagine a Sample D that is close to C, but even further from A, etc.)

Comment: It would probably be interesting to look at both options. It would be nice for a "quick and dirty" option, just to prescribe a uniform threshold for all variables and see what kinds of groups it makes but would also be interesting to use different clustering methods and see what it comes up with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a per-value comparison, a standard clustering method like DBSCAN or K-means will not work as those use the aggregate distance between points.

For this you can brute force it by comparing each item to all of the other items to find the maximum per-value difference (as a percentage).  The function `max_pct_difference` calculates the max percent difference.  These X-to-Y differences create the lower-half of a matrix of the "distances" you are interested in.

By pre-computing a distance matrix, you can use it in a clustering algorithm such as DBSCAN.  This will group together similar items that have a distance less than a parameter: epsilon.  You must be aware though, that not all items in a group will have a distance less than 10%.  This is because you can have samples such that A is within 10% of B, and B is within 10% C, but A and C are NOT within 10%:

```
A   1.0  1.0  1.0  2.1
B   1.0  1.0  1.0  2.3
C   1.0  1.0  1.0  2.4
```

Here is some code to get you started:

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

df = pd.DataFrame(
 {'Al': {'Sample1': 1.0, 'Sample2': 1.5, 'Sample3': 1.05, 'Sample4': 0.95},
  'Na': {'Sample1': 2.0, 'Sample2': 2.5, 'Sample3': 2.1, 'Sample4': 1.9},
  'K': {'Sample1': 3.0, 'Sample2': 3.5, 'Sample3': 3.1, 'Sample4': 3.1},
  'Si': {'Sample1': 4.0, 'Sample2': 4.5, 'Sample3': 1.0, 'Sample4': 3.8}}
)

def max_pct_difference(s1: tuple, s2: tuple):
    max_diff = 0.0
    for x, y in zip(s1[1:], s2[1:]):
        # handle division by zero
        if x == 0 and y == 0:
            continue
        diff = abs(x - y) / max(x, y)
        max_diff = max(diff, max_diff)
    return diff


pairs = []
for s1, s2 in combinations_with_replacement(df.itertuples(), 2):
    max_diff = max_difference(s1, s2)
    # append s1, s2 and then s2, s1 to make the matrix symmetric
    pairs.append((s1.Index, s2.Index, max_diff))
    if s1.Index != s2.Index:
        pairs.append((s2.Index, s1.Index, max_diff))


# this creates the distance matrix
dist_df = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns=['X', 'Y', 'd']).set_index(['X','Y']).unstack(level=1)
```

After creating the distance matrix, you can use DBSCAN to find the clusters/groups within a distance threshold, epsilon.  For the parameters, you will set `eps=0.1` and set the minimum points per cluster to 2 if you want to keep all of the groups that have at least 2 points that are close.  For the metric, we will use `"precomputed"` since we have precomputed the distances in a custom way.

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

dbs = DBSCAN(eps=0.1, min_samples=2, metric='precomputed')

# get the group label for each item in the distance data frame
groups = dbs.fit_predict(dist_df)

# assign the group label to the corresponding sample
df['Group'] = groups

print(df)
# prints:
#            Al   Na    K   Si  Group
# Sample1  1.00  2.0  3.0  4.0      0
# Sample2  1.50  2.5  3.5  4.5     -1
# Sample3  1.05  2.1  3.1  1.0     -1
# Sample4  0.95  1.9  3.1  3.8      0
```

There is only one group in this example, group `0`, which is assigned to samples 1 and 4. Rows labelled with group -1 do not have a group.

You can control the group membership by adjusting `eps` or by changing the how the distance is computed.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of recursions:

R

```
get_groups <- function(x, a = list()){
 r <-  colSums(abs(t(x) - (y<-unlist(x[1,])))/y > 0.1) == 0
 if(all(r)) c(a, list(x))
 else get_groups(x[!r, , drop = FALSE], c(a, list(x[r,, drop = FALSE])))
}

res <- get_groups(df)
res
[[1]]
          Al  Na   K  Si
Sample1 1.00 2.0 3.0 4.0
Sample4 0.95 1.9 3.1 3.8

[[2]]
         Al  Na   K  Si
Sample2 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5

[[3]]
          Al  Na   K Si
Sample3 1.05 2.1 3.1  1
```

---

Python

```
def get_groups(x, a = None):
  if a is None: a = []
  r = (x - (y := x.iloc[0])).abs().div(y).gt(0.1).sum(1) == 0
  if r.all():  return a + [x]
  return get_groups(x[~r], a + [x[r]])

res = get_groups(df)

res[0]
           Al   Na    K   Si
Sample1  1.00  2.0  3.0  4.0
Sample4  0.95  1.9  3.1  3.8

res[1]
          Al   Na    K   Si
Sample2  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5

res[2]
           Al   Na    K   Si
Sample3  1.05  2.1  3.1  1.0
```